# How to vertically align row items?

Tags: dart, flutter

Here's my code:

```
        child: new Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Icon(
                              Icons.call
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            height: 30.0,
                            width: 100.0,
                            child: new TextFormField(
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'User Name'),
                              validator: (val) =>
                              !val.contains('@')
                                  ? 'Not a valid email.'
                                  : null,
                              onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
                            ),

                          )

                        ],

                      ),
                    )
```

Here Icon and TextFormField isn't vertically aligned. TextFormField gives a margin top to itself and comes a bit down to the phone icon.

Comment: I have used this row widget in several places. So I want to get a solution regarding Row widget. @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `TextFormField` is going to add some padding around itself.  Since you just want to align the icon, you should probably just add it to your `InputDecoration`, and you can abandon using a `Row` entirely; you can also shift it down a bit to force it in line with the text entry bottom underline with some `Padding`:

```
new TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'User Name',
      icon: const Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          child: const Icon(Icons.call))),
  validator: (val) =>
      !val.contains('@') ? 'Not a valid email.' : null,
  onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
),
```

You can skip that `Padding` if you want it to be aligned the way Flutter thinks it's supposed to be, but I suspect you might still not be happy with it sitting as high as it does by default.

Comment: Thank you for improving the code and showing a more proper way.

Answer (score 26):

First remove the `height` property of the `Container` then set `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.center` which aligns the elements of the row to center with respect to vertical axis.

Example:

```
new Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Icon(Icons.call),
        new Container(
          width: 100.0,
          child: new TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'User Name'),
            validator: (val) =>
                !val.contains('@') ? 'Not a valid email.' : null,
            onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
          ),
        )
      ],
)
```

Comment: Edited my answer, checked it for myself and it works. Just remove the height property of container

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)